# Hola, porque python no me deja multiplicar, y 2 + 2 = 22?

Tags: python

este es mi código:

```
A = input("introducir un numero: ")
B = input("introducir otro numero: ")
resultado = A * B 
print("el resultado es: " + str(resultado))
```

este es el error que me salta:
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
PS C:\Users\felipe\Desktop\python>

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

El error es debido a que la funcion `input()` te captura los datos en tipo caracter/cadena
por ello al multiplicar te da error. Y por ello cuando sumas te da 22 porque te lo esta concatenando en lugar de sumarlo.

Para evitarlo converti tus variables a tipo entero `int()` antes de utilizarlas o de tipo float o cualquier otro dato numerico.

Podrias arreglarlo de esta manera.

```
A = int(input("introducir un numero: "))
B = int(input("introducir otro numero: "))
resultado = A * B 
print("el resultado es: ", resultado)
```

Comment: Notese que al hacer esto estás asumiendo que lo que escriba el usuario se puede interpretar como entero. Si el usuario ingresa la palabra "hola", ocurrirá un error.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me solucionaste el problema